# Introducing terms in the conclusion (natural deduction, propositional logic)

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I am just wanting to wrap my head around the following question;

$$A\to B \vDash ((A \land B) \to C) \to (A\to C)$$

So far all I am getting from the conclusion is that $A\to C$, if I introduce the conclusion as an assumption, but I am not sure how to tie it all together to go from the premise to the conclusion.

to clarify - I understand it is a tautology and I can translate it into English, I am struggling to show this via a fitch-style proof.

Answer (score 2):

If you know that B follows from A, and C follows from A *and* B, then C follows merely from A. After all, A gets you B, and then both get you C.

An example, for context:

> If it’s raining, then I carry an umbrella. Therefore, if it’s raining and I’m carrying an umbrella means that I’m dry, then if it’s raining, I’m dry.

You can deduce this  as follows:

$\def\fitch#1#2{~~~~\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}
{\fitch{1.\text{ Premise }A \to B}{\fitch{2.\text{ Assume }(A \wedge B) \to C)}{\fitch{3.\text{ Assume }A}{
4.\text{ Deduce }B\text{ from 1 and 3 }({\to}\mathsf E)\\
5.\text{ Deduce }A \wedge B\text{ from 3 and 4 }(\wedge\mathsf I)\\
6.\text{ Deduce }C\text{ from 2 and 5 }({\to}\mathsf E)}\\
7.\text{ Conclude }A \to C\text{ via 3 through 6 }({\to}\mathsf I)}\\
8.\text{ Conclude }((A \wedge B) \to C) \to (A \to C)\text{ via 2 through 7 }({\to}\mathsf I)}\\
\therefore\quad A\to B\vdash ((A\wedge B)\to C)\to(A\to C)}$

Comment: Thank you - yes I understand that, it makes sense to me. What I am struggling to do is put it all together in a fitch-style proof.

Comment: Dunno if it’s what you want, but I edited a proof in. I’m on mobile, so I couldn’t easily add Fitch-style symbols.

Comment: That looks a lot like what I have done so far, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The statement
$$(A \land B) \Rightarrow ((A \land B \Rightarrow C) \Rightarrow (A \Rightarrow C))$$
is a tautology, as you can see from the following truth table:

[image]

Comment: Hi there, thanks for that - sorry to clarify, I understand it is one, I am just struggling with how to get that without a truth table. I can translate it into English, but I don't know how to "get it" intuitively when turning it into fitch-style deduction.

Answer (score 0):

> $$A\to B \vDash ((A \land B) \to C) \to (A\to C)$$
>
> So far all I am getting from the conclusion is that $A\to C$, if I introduce the conclusion as an assumption,

*Never* introduce the consequent as an assumption.  It is what you seek to derive.  Assuming it will just have you running in circles.

> but I am not sure how to tie it all together to go from the premise to the conclusion.

What you assume is the *antecedent*, $(A\land B)\to C$, with the aim to *derive* the consequent $A\to C$; which in turn would be deduced by assuming its antecedent, $A$, and deriving its consequent, $C$.

Thus you need to nest Conditional Proofs: open with Assumptions and close with the relevant Conditional Introductions. $$\def\fitch#1#2{~~~~\begin{array}{|l} #1\\\hline #2\end{array}}\fitch{A\to B}{\fitch{(A\land B)\to C}{\fitch{A}{~\vdots\\C}\\A\to C}\\((A\land B)\to C)\to(A\to C)}$$

Well it should be clear how to derive $C$ from $A$, $A\to B$, and $(A\land B)\to C$ ...